# How [call] method works with class components in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, jestjs

I’m a newbie in Vuejs, I was studying the unit testing handbook today and saw the call method.

So if I don’t want to mount the component to test some complex computed property I can use call passing a different context to the method.

But I’m using Typescript and class components.

So my question is:
Does Call method works with class components?
If so, how does it work?

Comment: Please, be more specific. *I can use call passing a different context to the method.* - What is the code you're asking about? Do you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call ? Depending on how you do it, it may not work because Vue methods are bound to specific context. *So if I don’t want to mount the component to test some complex computed property* - seems like XY problem, you likely need to mount it.

Comment: Ok, here is the part of the Testing Handbook they use the call method, they are not using class component on test: https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/computed-properties.html#testing-with-call 
I think the better question is: how can I use call method with class component? 
I cannot mount the component cause if I do, I dont need call method.

Comment: In class comps, it like `Comp.$options.methods.method.call(...)`. But you don't need to do this. It cannot work for composition comps. You didn't explain why you can't mount the component. If you're new to Vue and testing, you can be sure things aren't done like this there. Comps are rendered with test renderer and tested.